# Removing system namespaces in doxygen

Tags: c#, doxygen

When I generate documentation using Doxygen I get several empty packages representing system namespaces like 'Linq' and so on. The question is how to get rid of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and found one solution. Putting the using ... lines between \cond and \endcond tags hides them in the helpfile output.
I'm not very glad about that, changing something in the doxy file would be easier. Maybe there's another better solution?
The problem is new with the new doxygen version v1.8.1.1

Comment: it is a solution, but putting \cond and \endcond to every file is lots of pain :(

Comment: I know that sucks but that's why I wrote I'm not very glad about the solution :( At the moment I don't know something better, if I find something out, I will tell you. If you find something, please tell me, too.

Answer (score 0):

I've removed them by adding this in the Doxyfile

```
EXCLUDE_SYMBOLS        = System
```